# Compiling Noble for Node Webkit on Windows10

Tags: node.js, nwjs

I've been working for days on trying to scan devices and write data on a Bluetooth Low Energy device using Node Webkit. After a lot of searches and trials, I read about Noble Nodejs addon and I was sure about the fact that Node Webkit could easily build all Nodejs addons (using nw-gyp tool). Nevertheless it seems very difficult to do that, probably because of the binding.gyp file missing. If I try to use noble through the `require('noble')` the 'DLL routine initialization error' appear (usually linked to a build missing):

### Uncaught Error: DLL initialization routine failed. \?\C:...\node_modules\usb\src\binding\usb_bindings.node at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:760:18) at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:623:32) at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:12) at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:554:3) at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:661:17) at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18) at Object. (C:...\node_modules\usb\usb.js:5:38) at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:30) at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:730:10) at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:623:32)

I also tried to configure through nw-gyp or using nw-pre-gyp without success.
Did anyone already dealt with this problem or could give me some hints about how to compile a nodejs addon (or noble itself) in this conditions?
Thank you very much.

PS: my system features are: OS: Win10, NW: 0.32.4, NodeJS: 10.9.0

Comment: Are you using the official `noble` package? If so, are you trying to use `bluetooth-hci-socket`? That is likely the module that needs to be compiled. 

`cd node_modules/bluetooth-hci-socket`
`nw-gyp rebuild --target=0.32.4`

Comment: If you are building for Windows 10 only, you can also use the noble-winrt module: `npm install git+https://git@github.com/Timeular/noble-winrt.git`